# How to retrieve the value of an MDTextFieldRound on kivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've been looking for a few days how to retrieve the text written in MDTextFieldRound on Kivy.
So if you have the answers to my questions do not hesitate to write.
Blux

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Use the `text` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works best for me if I set a texfield id, which I then access in python.
**For example in .kv:**

```
MDTextFieldRect:
      id: user_name  (Here is a id)
      font_size: 0.65 * self.height
      size_hint: 1, .8
      max_text_length: 9
      pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

**And then in in .py:**
When you want to change a text in field:

```
class ProfileWindow(Screen):

    def clear_info(self):
        self.ids['user_name'].text = ""
        self.ids['user_pass'].text = ""
        self.ids['user_address'].text = ""
        self.ids['user_number'].text = ""
```

Or if you want to get the text from text field:

```
def clear_info(self):

    name = self.ids['user_name'].text
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to recover the text written while the application is running.

Comment: If I get your point, you can store the text what was written to text field to:                
    def build(self):
        semething = StringProperty(None)
        usernameL = StringProperty(None)                                                                                                                    After that you can save your text to app.something and get it same way. If this is not what you wanted you can give me example of your problem